# geo location normalizer - Bulk requests

Tags: geolocation, openstreetmap, geocoding, nominatim, normalizing

I am doing a POC for functionality to normalize address information. I am playing with Nominatim. I am running a docker container on my local machine with the nominatim image, and do my requests against that.

This all works fine now, but the application will have to be able to process around 1200 addresses per second. Now a round-trip to the server will cost about a second, so I will never be able to make 1200 requests in a second. Even with multi-threading and scaling up the amount of services this will probably not work like this.

I think if I would be able to ask for a whole bulk of addresses in one request, that would save a lot of valuable resources, but I don't see any documentation in Nominatim about bulk processing. Does anyone know if this is at all possible, and if not, do you perhaps know of another tool that can be used on our own server that does support this?

I hope someone can help me out with this, and point me in the right direction.

Comment: A round trip to the server takes one second? Is this [IP over avian carriers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_over_Avian_Carriers)?

Comment: Turns out I forgot to set the domain in the nominatim constructor...

Comment: So it went to the default openstreetmaps server, which probably did not like me bulk loading their data :-) Now I get about 25 to 28 addresses per second with 20 threads on my PC. I will try what speed I can get when deploying this on an AWS server, but the 1200 /